# How to test the view using a test server in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I've got a couple of files in my view that I'm now beginning to design visually (through CSS) by vising the local web app in my browser. To get to these views, you have to go through an authentication step in my application.

Now when testing the authentication step in a controller, I use a fixture containing some test login credentials. This allows me test other parts of the application after this step. However if I wanted to test using the server, I would have to use real credetials from the database. Am I supposed to put fake data in the 'development' database so I can do this, and instead use real data in the 'production' database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is called integration testing (or end-to-end testing). Rails provides integration testing out [of the box](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing).

Personal preferences : I use [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) with the [Capybara DSL](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara), and seed data corresponding to my features/scenarios using Cucumber's [hooks](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks).

**EDIT** : at first read, I didn't understand that by "testing" you meant "manual testing". In this case yes, you'd better seed your development database with fake data corresponding to your features/test cases.

Comment: Ah, cool. I'm actually just trying to test how the view looks visually in the browser, so the last part of your answer sounds like the way to go.